# List of nested classes in Java?

Tags: java, list, nested

Is there a way to make list of nested classes objects?

I defined my nested classes like this:

```
public class AB{

    public class A {    }

    public class B {    }
```

I want to make list like this:

```
List<AB> listAB = new ArrayList<>();
AB.A objectA = AB.new A();
AB.B objectB = AB.new B();

listAB.add(objectA);
listAB.add(objectB);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I did tried it and it doesn't work. Am asking for other possibilities.

Comment: Nested classes are *not* implicitly subtypes of their containers. But subtyping sucks anyway, use interfaces :)

Comment: no because they are different classes, it will work if you make `A` and `B` subclasses of `AB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make A and B subclass of AB. And both A and B should be static class.

```
public class AB{

public static class A extends AB {    }

public static class B extends AB{    }
}
```

Then your list will work:

```
List<AB> listAB = new ArrayList<AB>();
AB.A objectA = AB.new A();
AB.B objectB = AB.new B();

listAB.add(objectA);
listAB.add(objectB);
```

Comment: I forgot to make the class of A and B static. Just modified my code. @Makoto

Comment: Yes. Because that's not how you instantiate those objects.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work with that syntax.  Neither `A` nor `B` relate to `AB` (that is, they cannot be assigned in place of `AB`), even if they are nested.

Further, you won't be able to access those classes outside of the enclosing class without the declarations being `static`.

What you should do is:

- Change your class declaration to the following:

  ```
  public static class A extends AB { }
  public static class B extends AB { }
  ```

  ...and then, we see that both `A` and `B` relate to `AB` (that is, they can be assigned in place of an `AB`).
- Correct the instantiation invocation of `AB.A` and `AB.B`:

  ```
  AB.A objectA = new AB.A();
  AB.B objectB = new AB.B();
  ```

Then, you can add to your list without trouble.

Comment: Thank you! The "static" resolved my issue with this$0 field - I used AB.A.class.getDeclaredField() for getting all the fields of nested class but I also got the "this$0" which caused me troubles.